# Response.End() in Java/JSP

Tags: java, jsp

In .net you have the ability to Response.End() in any context you want. Is there similar functionality in Java/JSP?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience you have to do the following:

```
out.flush(); // Send out whatever hasn't been sent out yet.
out.close(); // Close the stream. Future calls will fail.
return; // Return from the JSP servelet handler.
```

**NOTE:** 
This will **not** work inside a function because you'll just end up returning from the function but not from the JSP servelet handler (which I'm assuming is your intention).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
servletResponse.getOutputStream().close();
```

Not quite sure if that will have odd side effects though, in case the server needs to send any data after your content...

[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close())

Comment: When I do something like what I am doing below, nothing gets written to the browser, I would think that 'TEST' would get written and thats the behavior I am trying to achieve, Any suggestions?

<%
out.println("TEST");
response.getOutputStream().close();
out.println("TEST2");

Comment: "out" isn't the same thing as response.getOutputStream() -- have you tried out.close()?