# how to compare the result of success function of ajax with a string

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
 $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "test.jsp",
        data:           "user="+name.val(),
        success:    function(msg) {

            $('#result').hide();

            $("#result").html(msg)
            .fadeIn("slow"); 
                              if( msg =="available")
                                 {

                                      alert(msg);
                            }


        }
    });

test.jsp
   <h1>
    <%
    String user=request.getParameter("user");
    if(user.equals("prerna"))
    out.print("available");
    else
        out.print("not available");
    %>
   </h1>
```

i want to compare the value returned by success function to be compared with a string
but the above code is not working
i also want to add the css class to the "#result" id.
the alert box is not comming.

Comment: place an alert inside success function `alert(msg);` and see what it says...also try `if(msg.toString()==='available')`

Comment: if(msg.toString()==='available') is not working

Comment: replacing the available with double quotes is also not working

Comment: which is the result if you do "alert (msg)" in the first line of the function of "success"?

Answer (score 19):

**Something there is a blank space. With $.trim() function you can delete all blank spaces. It works!!!**

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
success: function(data) {
    var result = $.trim(data);
    if(result==="available"){
        alert("available");
    return false;
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url : 'saveDeviceLike.php',
    success : function(data){
        var reply = data.replace(/\s+/, ""); //remove any trailing white spaces from returned string
        if (reply == 'success')
        $('#pleaseWait').html('Your have successfully registered for this competition.<br/>You will be contacted via mail.');
        if (reply == 'registered')
        $('#pleaseWait').html('You have already been registered for the competition!');
        if (reply == 'failed')
        $('#pleaseWait').html('Your registration cannot be completed now.<br/>Please try again later.');
```

}

//Make sure you use the replace function to strip of any extra spaces

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem in ajax comparison is unwanted space:

```
var result = $.trim(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not print HTML `<h1>` element around the ajax response in JSP. Get rid of it. You need to ensure that you have **nothing** before `<%` and after `%>` in JSP, even no whitespace/newlines. JSP would emit them anyway. Actually, a JSP is the wrong tool for the job. A servlet is a better suit for the job.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String message = "not available";

    if ("prerna".equals(user)) {
        message = "available";
    }
    
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(message);
}
```

This will work fine with jQuery `dataType: text`. Even more, it's not strictly required to set the data type here.

#### Related questions:

- [Update current page with a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataType to 'text'.  If that doesn't work, then make sure that 'available' really is the only thing being returned, with no line endings or spaces or anything.

Comment: how to set the datatype to test,

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the data type for ajax response, for example:

```
// text

$.ajax({
   dataType: "text",
    type: "post",
    url: "test.jsp",
    data: "user="+name.val(),
    success: function(msg) {

        $("#result")
            .hide();
            .html(msg)
            .fadeIn("slow"); 

        if(msg == "available") {
            alert("is available");
        }

    }
 });

// json

$.ajax({
   dataType: "text",
    type: "post",
    url: "test.jsp",
    data: "user="+name.val(),
    success: function(data) {

        $("#result")
            .hide();
            .html(data.msg)
            .fadeIn("slow"); 

        if(data.msg == "available") {
            alert("is available");
        }

    }
 });
```

[Specifying the Data Type for AJAX Requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) 
[doc jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**EDIT**

try this options:

```
// text

$.ajax({
   dataType: "text",
    type: "post",
    url: "test.jsp",
    data: "user="+name.val(),
    success: function(msg) {

        $("#result")
            .hide();
            .html(msg)
            .fadeIn("slow"); 

        if(msg.indexOf("not available") > -1) {
            alert("not available");
        }
        else if(msg.indexOf("available") > -1) {
            alert("available");
        }


    }
 });

// html

$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    type: "post",
    url: "test.jsp",
    data: "user="+name.val(),
    success: function(data) {

        $("#result")
            .hide();
            .html(data)
            .fadeIn("slow"); 

        if($(data).filter(":contains(not available)").length > 0) {
            alert("not available");
        }
        else if($(data).filter(":contains(available)").length > 0) {
            alert("available");
        }

    }
 });
```

Ideally, your file "test.jsp" was as follows:

```
<%
String user=request.getParameter("user");
if(user.equals("prerna"))
  out.print("available");
else
  out.print("not available");

out.flush(); // Send out whatever hasn't been sent out yet.
out.close(); // Close the stream. Future calls will fail.
return; // Return from the JSP servelet handler.

%>
```

the end is based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570929/response-end-in-java-jsp)

Comment: in your question, I put a comment to see which is the result of the variable msg. if you can put the result and also how it returns data from "test.jsp"

Comment: available is getting returned by result

Comment: but i want to compare it so that i can display the user correct symbol to indicate availabilty of user id

Answer (score 0):

```
                    success:function(response){

                    if(response=="yes")
                            {
                                    myFunction();
                            }else{

                                myFunctionn();
                            }

                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some more explanation about your code and suggested answer.